# omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

```
Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/linkedin/callback?code=...&state=..." for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-09-14 20:50:20 +0200
D, [2022-09-14T20:50:20.537126 #37240] DEBUG -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2022-09-14T20:50:21.021252 #37240] ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_request: A required parameter "client_secret" is missing
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"client_secret\" is missing"}
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
```

- ruby version 3.2.0
- rails version 7.0.4

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can confirm that your fix does indeed work. Thank you! I'm adding it to my app to the config/initializers.rb as**

```
 module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class LinkedIn < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      def token_params
        super.tap do |params|
          params.client_secret = options.client_secret
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`Add this in your code`

> lib/strategies/linkedin.rb

`And also this code in your devise.rb`

> require "strategies/linkedin"

Comment: Hi there! I have the same problem But unfortunately this solution didn't help me. Now I've hot another Error:
`You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method SnakyHash::StringKeyed#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.`
Could you advise me something here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to rails and coding so I cannot offer any explanation to this issue and I was struggling for hours, I was using devise, so a workaround to this for me was to downgrade oauth2 version by adding:

```
gem 'oauth2', '~> 1.0'
```

in my Gemfile and running:

```
$ bundle install
```

My guess is this has something to do with JSON and I am not sure if it will affect devise functionality. The answer by [Bhavesh Vadhvana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19477105/bhavesh-vadhvana) also works.

Comment: I had tried this before, but I have not only integrated Login with Linkedin, but can also login through facebook and google.
If you downgrade version of oauth2 gem then login with google will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023-08 a fix for this issue is to upgrade the omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 gem to the latest version (as https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2/pull/71 has been merged and released as v1.0.1).